# CSP Blocking Styles and Scripts while using Angular 10

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

Alittle background: I have created a an angular web application and I am at the point in the project life cycle where it is time to deploy. For some reason that i cannot understand is that CSP is blocking my local CSS files from being used. I have read through every thread on here regarding "quick fixes" to this but have not reached a solution. The CSP policy that i am using is

```
<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy"
content="default-src 'none' unsafe-inline;
script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com unsafe-inline;
connect-src 'self' unsafe-inline; 
img-src 'self' unsafe-inline; 
style-src 'self' unsafe-inline;
base-uri 'self' unsafe-inline;
form-action 'self' unsafe-inline" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide fragments of code or the CSP messages about blocking the scripts and styles, i'll try to "treat patient by his photo".

**Variant 1**. The `'self'` token implies the same scheme/host/port as the page is loaded.
Therefore if you load a web application by `http://localhost:5000`, then 'self' will only allow loading styles and scripts from `http://localhost:5000/path_to` (port nbr cannot be omitted).
You have somewhere not matched port, scheme or host_name.

**Variant 2**. You have a 2 CSPs (both are via meta tag or meta + HTTP header), and one of those CPSs is very rectrictive.

Comment: I am sure that i am not declaring two CSP's, as for I have only added one inside of my index.html file generated with angular cli. I will look into the port-scheme-host_name issue.

Comment: Can you show CSP blocking messages in the Chrome browser console?